# How to add a form model property to dropzone widget in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii-extensions, yii2-advanced-app

I am using a dropzone file uploader but it does not take a model property in an active form

The dropzone widget is:

```
echo \kato\DropZone::widget([
                       'options' => [
                          'url'=>'upload',
                           'maxFilesize' => '200',
                           'addRemoveLinks'=>true,

                       ],
                       'clientEvents' => [
                           'complete' => "function(file){console.log(file)}",
             'removedfile' => "function(file){alert(file.name + ' is removed')}"
                       ],
                   ]);
```

I have tried

```
echo $form->field($model, 'picture')->widget(\kato\DropZone::widget([
                       'options' => [
                           'url'=>'upload',
                           'maxFilesize' => '200',
                           'addRemoveLinks'=>true,

                       ],
                       'clientEvents' => [
                           'complete' => "function(file){console.log(file)}",
             'removedfile' => "function(file){alert(file.name + ' is removed')}"
                       ],
                   ]));
```

But it returns an error like this

```
Class '<div id="myDropzone" class="dropzone"><div id="previews" 
class="dropzone-previews"></div></div>' not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually it should be:

```
use kato\DropZone;

...

echo $form->field($model, 'picture')->widget(DropZone::className, [
    'options' => [
        'url'=>'upload',
        'maxFilesize' => '200',
        'addRemoveLinks'=>true,
    ],
    'clientEvents' => [
        'complete' => "function(file) { console.log(file) }",
        'removedfile' => "function(file) {alert(file.name + ' is removed') }",
    ],
]);
```

So in the first parameter you pass a class name, in the second - configurational array with options.

But I looked at [sources](https://github.com/perminder-klair/yii2-dropzone) of a widget, there is no support for that. Use it without `ActiveField`, or create issue / send a pull request for this extension on GitHub.

**Official docs:**

[yii\widgets\ActiveField widget()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#widget%28%29-detail)